# 3D Book mockup background-image position

Tags: css

So I'm trying to make a 3D book mockup. Each of this 3D mockup facets have scans of the book's respective sections. Everything works fine except the top section of the book you can see in the image.

[image]

Here, the image I input is vertical:

[image]

I'm trying to place this image horizontally (and not vertically and blurred) as it seems to be.
This should be like this:

[image]

My CSS is:

```
    background-image: url(img_url_here);
    width: 459px;
    height: 72px;
    transform: translate3d(-229.5px, -336px, 36px) translate3d(0px, -36px, -36px) rotateX(90deg);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
```

What am I doing wrong?